# Civ:BE not containing mouse on multiple monitors

Tags: monitor, civilization-beyond-earth

I've been playing *Civilization: Beyond Earth* on a PC with two monitors, with the game running on the left monitor. However, the cursor isn't constrained by the right side of the left monitor, which makes it irritating to scroll across the map. I'm running it in fullscreen, which has generally worked for all other games I've played (including Civ V). I haven't found anything on this by Googling. Is this a known issue with Civ:BE?

(System specs: Windows 8.1 x64, 2 x 1920x1080 monitors, nVidia GTX 550 Ti, running game in normal (non-mantle) mode)

Comment: FYI, you can also scroll the map by left-clicking and dragging. Often, I find myself doing this more often than hitting the edges of the map anyway.

Comment: @Chaosed0 Yeah, I just tend to prefer passively panning if I'm going to look at a location farther than one or two drags away. Good to know that both are options though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you go into the Interface Options section of the Options menu, you should find this option right here:

[image: Civ BE's Bind Mouse option]

Flip it to either Fullscreen or Always, to suit your preference, and your mouse will no longer be free to wander to your other monitor.